# What kind of data suits ARIMA forecasting?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima

I understand that an ARMA series is of the form
$y_t   =   \mu + \phi_{1} y_{t-1} +…+ \phi_{p} y_{t-p} - \theta_{1} e_{t-1} -…- \theta_{q} e_{t-q}$

Can any form of quantitative variable ( price, income, profit, etc) be forecasted using ARMA?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as long as all diagnostic tests for the residuals hold.

Comment: But how can we always hold that "future is an expansion of the past" when in reality, the variable is actually in the influence of a number of other independent variables. Eg. Profit depends on the sales in that year and other economic conditions. How can we say that the profit this year is an expansion of profit in the previous years?

Comment: Those are some insightful comments one can make and good to keep in mind. However, note that a prediction is merely a 'best guess' one could make with data at hand. In a numerical case, the predicted value is ALWAYS wrong. However, if we know something about the predicted value and more importantly the uncertainty around the predicted value, then we could make 'informative' decisions. It's nothing more nor less.

Comment: It is also good to note that IF the past is completely different from the current and future, then it does not make sense to even bother to construct a prediction model. Basically, there is no serial correlation in the data to employ!

Comment: the past is always a proxy for omitted causal variables. The future is never caused by the past but by variables that are either known and unknown. In the absence of the causals the past can sometimes be useful.